# How to set default value of "props" when props.data is bind by REST API call using @connect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set default value for prop "data" in the react component. I don't want to keep this code part of "render" function, instead I want to keep it part of constructor or some other life cycle event. However I realized that when I am keeping inside "constructor" then it throws "Cannot assign to read only property" error. However when I keep it in other lifecycle event then changes are not reflecting. Following are code for reference. Not sure what is right way to set the default value of props.data.

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Country from "./Country";

@connect(state => ({data: state.example.data}))
export default class Countries extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    props.data = props.data || []; //This throws exception that  Cannot assign to read only property
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount (props) {
    console.log("componentWillMount");
    props.data = props.data || []; //This change doesn't solve the issue.
  }
  componentDidMount (props) {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    props.data = props.data || []; //Since render function fail therefore execution flow doesn't reach here.
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps (props) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    props.data = props.data || []; //Since render function fail therefore execution flow doesn't reach here.
  }
  render() {

    const data = this.props.data; //This needs constructor or lifecycle method to set default value.
    //const data = this.props.data || []; //This works

    console.log("Countries  this.props "+ JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (<div className='container'>
      <table className='table table-bordered table-striped'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Capital</th>
          <th>Population</th>
          <th>Domain</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         { data.map(country => { return (<Country key={country.name} country={country} />)})} //This throws exception as "data" is undefined at beginning. therefor need to set default value.
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React props are frozen on component creation. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#breaking-changes.

You must either perform your ajax call then create the component with props using results of that request, use setState to mutate the component, or clone the element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to do this in your connect function:

```
connect(state => ({data: state.example.data || []}))
```